# Как складывать время на Android?

Tags: java, android

Как программно посчитать время. Необходимо время с TextClock  прибавить 20 мин которое записано в TextView В TextView время может менять 20, 40, 110, 180 и т.д.

Comment: В чем вопрос? С чем возникли сложности: с получением времени, с получением количества минут, с прибавлением?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Текст в `TextView` - это множество букв, которое можно преобразовать в строку. А её можно преобразовать в число.

```
long minutes = Long.valueof(textView.getText().toString());
```

Далее нужно вспомнить сколько миллисекунд в минуте и перевести минуты в миллисекунды:

```
long minutesInMillis = minuts * 60L * 1000L;
```

Теперь можно, например, прибавить полученные миллисекунды к текущему времени:

```
long nowPlusMinutes = System.currentTimeMillis() + minutesInMillis;
```

Comment: Для уточнения, получается, что currentTimeMillis() переводит время взятое с телефона, например:"15:10", получается в миллисекундах "54360000" и складывает с заданным временем, например: 40мин(в милсек = 40000), результат полученных данных 54360000+40000=54400000. Как мне привести эти данные в типовой вид HH:MM

Comment: @Weyner, `new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm").format(nowPlusMinutes )`

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!